# Can we execute a script as root during docker container startup?

Tags: linux, boot, docker, container

I am trying to execute a script during container startup.

For a normal linux machine, if i have script in `/etc/rc.local` script will be executed when there is reboot

I am trying to do the same thing, when building Docker image. I override the `/etc/rc.local` file with new content, then I perform

```
sudo docker run -d <image id>
```

I was expecting `/etc/rc.local` would be executed, however nothing happens.

Am I doing it in the wrong place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker only runs the process (or processes) that you tell it to run.

Docker containers normally don't have a functioning init system. They are not like virtual machines that contain a complete operating system that executes all the initialisation when it is booted.

If you want `/etc/rc.local` to run, you have to start it yourself. Something like:

`docker run image /bin/bash -c "/etc/rc.local; <your command>"`

There are some alternative base images that support running services on start-up, e.g. [phusion/baseimage-docker](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker).

Read [this article](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/) to understand what the problems and issues are with Docker and starting a container.